# Does anyone has working Delphi 7 code, class or unit to upload Tweets to Twitter?

Tags: delphi, twitter, delphi-7

Does any one has succesfully created a unit or Delphi 7 class to upload tweets to the TWitter web site ?

I would like to be able to add tweets from within my Delphi program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Twitter class for Delphi code](http://chuckbeasley.com/index.php/2009/05/28/twitter-for-delphi-code/)

[RadTweet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/radtweet/develop) a twitter client written in Delphi

[Dwitterphi](http://dwitterphi.assembla.com/wiki/show/dwitterphi) another twitter client written in Delphi

Answer (score 1):

http://eden.fm/2011/02/27/twitter-library-for-delphi/